# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

Estimados consulta tengo un proyecto laravel con tenancy multiinquilino esta desplegado en `aws`, esta ya funcionando, el problema que se tiene es al crear un cliente o inquilino me sale error interno del servidor, revisando la base de datos me esta creando la base de datos pero no es capaz de crear las tablas correspondientes y me he fijado que la base del cliente la crea pero sin privilegios por lo cual entiendo no puede ejecutar la acción de creación de tablas, consulto hay alguna configuración de lado de laravel o tenancy para permitir estos privilegios o es de lado del servidor de `aws`, en teoría la BD, principal si tiene **user: pass:** y todos los privilegios, el problema es con la bd de los inquilinos o cientes que no le otorga dichos privilegios. alguna idea ?

Gracias.

**error:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist

error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist
/var/www/html/facturacion_electronica/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php#43

Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist
/var/www/html/facturacion_electronica/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php#41

debo hacer algo como esto: eliminar transacciones al crear inquilinos

alguna idea: Gracias

Comment: Deberías editar tu pregunta y agregar el mensaje de error que se grabó en el log de errores

Comment: ¿Lograste dar con el problema? Estoy teniendo el mismo ahora

Comment: No sé si en aws se nesecita algo en particular. Cree una instancia en Google cloud e instale todo desde cero y allí no me lanzó ese error. Funcionó sin problemas. El motivo no lo se pero en aws no lo puede resolver. Intenta con una cuenta de Google cloud .